# Titanium JavaScript event handler and class scope

Tags: javascript, titanium

developing under Titanium I have encountred this strange behaviour with OOP JavaScript and event handler scope. This is my code:

```
MyClass = function()
{
   this.var1 = '50';
   this.button = Ti.UI.createButton({
      ...
   });
   this.button.parentRef = this;
   this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      var self = e.source.parentRef;
      console.log(self.var1);
      console.log(self.var2);
   });

   this.var2 = 'Test';
   ...
   /* this.button is then added to a view */
};
... 
var c = new MyClass();
...
```

When I click on the button, in my console I would expect to find:

```
50
Test
```

But actually the result is:

```
50
<null>
```

If I move the assignment

> this.var2 = 'Test'

before the

> this.button.addEventListener

statement, the result is:

```
50
Test
```

Sounds like that the this.button.parentRef = this assignment is by copy and not by reference...

What is the cause of this behavior ?

Comment: Are you sure the `e.source` is the button itself? It's not even a standard event property.

Comment: Does `Ti.UI.createButton` return the actual DOM element (on which the event is fired) itself or does it create a wrapper?

Comment: @Bergi It creates a [proxy object](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/02/what-is-a-titanium-proxy-object.html) to a native android/ios button

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: Oops, that might invalidate my answer. Thank you, I should have looked for that myself. Do you know whether the events are proxied as well?

Comment: @Bergi the source event attribute is documented here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-click

Comment: I didn't got the actual problem at first, and since my answer does (did) not target it I don't think it's worth keeping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.

What you are doing has wrinkles with Titanium, whenever you add an attribute to a *Titanium* native object, it is passed by value, as the underlying object (your view) is actually a *native* mapped to a JavaScript object. So what happens is that the current value of that object (in your case `this`) is sent across the Javascript-to-native bridge and set as a property of the native object (or something like that).

What it comes down to is that, any attributes on a native object you set are pretty much cloned by the object, thats why you are seeing the above functionality.

So what are some ways to deal with this?

This is the easy way:

```
var self = this;
this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(self.var1);
    console.log(self.var2);
});
```

It somewhat pollutes your button listener scope, but at least its not in global scope.